# disable caching for *nocache*-Files in Apache

Tags: windows, apache, gwt

I tried to disable caching for my GWT app with the following configuration in httpd.conf (Windows), but it doesn't work:

```
<filesMatch ".*nocache.*">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule headers_module>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</filesMatch>
```

But I still can't see any of these headers in the response from the server. Any Idea? (the headers_module is activated)

Comment: Shouldn't `filesMatch` be `FilesMatch`? Have you tried `Files`? Have you tried the config at https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#perfect_caching ?

Comment: `FilesMatch`: doesn't work, `Files`: doesn't work, the config from developers.google.com: doesn't work. I use mod_jk, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: It can very well be. I seem to remember some issues with it, depending on the versions of Apache and mod_jk, the order of the various config statements, and possibly the presence of a trailing slash in the URL configured in mod_jk.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Thomas for your help. I think the problem is because with `mod_jk` apache does not really send files. I found the [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/260184/problem-with-filesmatch-not-matching-correctly) which helped a lot. I just had to replace `FilesMatch` with `LocationMatch`:

```
<LocationMatch ".*nocache.*">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule headers_module>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: I should use this regex, it's a little more precise: `.*\.nocache(\..*)?`. It is: all files containing `dot-nocache-dot` in the name... or those ending in `dot-nocache`.